# Function over different arrays and indexes

Tags: python, numpy

I want to perform an operation over two arrays `x = [1, 2, 3, ...]` and `y = [4, NaN, NaN, ...]`. The goal is to compute the remaining values for array y using scalars and the previous index, for example, `y[1] = (y[0] * 7 + x[1]) / 8`, `y[2] = (y[1] * 7 + x[2]) / 8`, ... I have tried things along the lines of `y[1:] = (y[0:len(y) - 1] * 7 + x[1:]) / 8`, but get completely wrong results. How can I create this kind of operations in numpy? A for loop would be too inefficient?

Comment: Since each element of `y` depends on the previous value, you have to calculate them one-by-one... a vectorized operation doesn't make sense here; vectorization requires *something* to be loaded into memory whereupon a single instruction (like "add") is executed on two arrays of numerical data. In other words, you need all your data *a priori* in order to take advantage of vectorization.

Comment: From a more mathematical standpoint, what you're describing is what's commonly referred to as a "recurrence relation". It's a mathematical *object* defined purely in *iterative* terms. In other words, there is no other way to generate a recurrence relation *other than iteratively*.

Comment: @ddejohn thank you for the reply! I will keep my current for loop then.

Comment: This is a serious question. In general this can't be optimized in `numpy` unless you use some pencil & paper to obtain analytic expression of recurrent relation of the form `A * y[i+1] + B * y[i] == x[i+1]`. I have shown in my solution how to do that but it's still `O(n²)` which is much slower than a simple loop. But you could improve it if your array `x` is quite simple like in your case and you know a general formula of expression `(n-1) + (n-2)*7/8 + (n-3)*(7/8)**2+  ... 1*(7/8)**(n-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to do like this:

```
for i in range(N):
    y[i+1] = (y[i] * 7 + x[i+1]) / 8
```

So I'm pretty sure it's worth calling it 'looping in Python level'. From [Introduction of numpy vectorized operations](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html#Vectorized-Operations):

> NumPy provides highly-optimized functions for performing mathematical operations on arrays of numbers. Performing extensive iterations (e.g. via ‘for-loops’) in Python to perform repeated mathematical computations should nearly always be replaced by the use of vectorized functions on arrays. This informs the entire design paradigm of NumPy.

There is no straightforward way of vectorization in your case. At least, you can try mathematical approach since this kind of relation is known widely

> A relation of the form `A * y[i+1] + B * y[i] == f(i)` is said to be linear first-order non-homogeneous difference recurrence equation

In order to move further, you can rearrange this into:

```
y[n+1] = (7/8) * y[n] + x[n+1]/8
```

Based on this formula, a remaining part of solution looks like:

```
y[1] = (7/8) * y[0] + x[1]/8
y[2] = 7/8 * [(7/8) * y[0] + x[1]/8] + x[2]/8 = (7/8)**2*y[0] + 7/8*x[1]/8 + x[2]/8
...
```

So you can conclude that

```
y[n] = (7/8)**n*y[0] + x[n]/8 + (7/8)*x[n-1]/8 + (7/8)**2*x[n-2]/8 + ... + (7/8)**(n-1)*x[1]
```

Hence finding previous item `y[i-1]` is not required in order to find `y[i]` anymore. Now let's find `[y[1], y[2], ... y[n]]` in one go according to the formula that we've got in terms of [general `numpy` broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

You need to add `Y` =

```
y[0]*(7/8)
y[0]*(7/8)**2
y[0]*(7/8)**3
       ...
y[0]*(7/8)**(n
```

with a result of product `V =`

```
1   0        0        0  ...     0
1 7/8        0        0  ...     0
1 7/8 (7/8)**2        0  ...     0
1 7/8 (7/8)**2 (7/8)**3  ...     0
.  .      .        .             .
·  ·      ·        ·             ·
'  '      '        '             '
1 7/8 (7/8)**2 (7/8)**3  ... (7/8)**(n-1)
```

and `X =`

```
 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...
 2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...
 3  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...
 4  3  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...
 5  4  3  2  1  0  0  0  0  0 ...
 6  5  4  3  2  1  0  0  0  0 ...
...
```

I'll provide a `numpy` solution for this, not the best looking but you could refactor it:

```
n = 10
y = np.empty(n+1)
y[0] = 4
R = np.repeat([1, 7/8], [1, n])
Y = np.cumprod(R[1:])
V = np.tril(np.vander(R, increasing=True))[:-1,:-1]
X = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.r_[np.zeros(n-1), np.arange(1, n+1)], n)[:, ::-1]
T1, T2 = (Y*y[0], np.sum(V*X/8, axis=1))
y[1:] = T1 + T2
>>> y
[4.         3.625      3.421875   3.36914062 3.44799805 3.64199829
 3.9367485  4.31965494 4.77969807 5.30723581 5.89383134]
```

In general it's `O(n²)` in comparison with initial method which is `O(n)`. If you know formulas of terms of `np.sum(V*X, axis=1)`, this could reach `O(n)` and outperform the first way.